# iterate over sub documents from mongodb in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hashmap

I'm trying to store a hashmap in the database and retrieve it later for processing
but I don't know how to iterate over the data (map) I retrieved from the result
Here is my code

```
var mongodbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/users';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var HashMap = require('hashmap');

var map = new HashMap();
var key = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2
};
var value = 10;
map.set(key, value);

var data = {
    "mp": map,
    "room": 3
};
MongoClient.connect(mongodbUrl, function (err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection('draw');
    collection.insert(data);
    collection.findOne({"room" : 3}).then(function (result) {

        var m1 = new HashMap();
        m1 = result.mp;

        // not working
        m1.forEach(function (value, key) {
            // operate on value, key
        });

    });
});
```

If there is no way to store it as a map directly again, is there a way to just iterate on this data?

Comment: Hi Hossam, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you describe what goes wrong when you try to iterate over result.map?

Comment: it says that "m1.forEach is not a function".